# Issue with asp.net Client ID

Tags: asp.net

I've been using javascript/jquery in ASP.NET apps for awhile, and for whatever reason this application is different that I'm working on.

If I have a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

and i try to reference it by the clientID like this

```
 var example = $get('<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value;
```

Or a bunch of similar ways trying to get the clientID that i've tried, the page throws and error and redirect to my error page...

But if I just reference it by it's actual ID, it works fine. I've always had to use the clientID before with asp.net and getting the values with Javascript. What could be the reason that it's actually getting the correct ID now, and not liking my ClientID approach?

Comment: The code that you've post has an error: it is `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"</asp:TextBox>`and it should be `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>` Have you checked that?

Comment: Sorry, yes I must have accidentally deleted that out when I was removing some unimportant information from that textbox control to post here.

Comment: Have you checked the server response? I mean, what is the html actually generated for the TextBox section and for the javascript section? Can you post it?

Comment: <input name="txtFirstName" type="text" id="txtFirstName" class="textbox" onkeyup="myfunction()" />

Comment: and which is the rendered javascript? once you see it, you can copy and paste it in the JS console in the browser, then you can see which is the error if any

Answer (score -1):

$('#<%= txtbx.ClientId %>').val()